# Fabric How to view/ export events' details

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

While I've successfully reported custom events to Fabric, I'm not able to view the details of the events.

Hovering the graph and the table gives me snippets of the **event logs** but the text strings are **cut off**, it's so frustrating

There are 2 "download" buttons in the following screenshot.
However, clicking on them only gives me the count of the events, not the events themselves
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Can't see whole details

Comment: Me too. Asked it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46390701/373106, still no solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something that works for me for now:

1. Click on 1 Crashlytics crash
2. Click on a version number under **Recent Activity**
3. There I can view the log from `Crashlytics.log(int priority, String tag, String msg);` together with the user's ID and hashed email

[image][image]

Comment: How is it related to the question?

Comment: I dont know where the misunderstanding is but feel free to edit the question if you feel it's misleading @vahotm

Answer (score 13):

Mike from Fabric here. There is not currently a way to download the custom attributes associated with Answers' events. Noted that you'd love to have this added in.

Comment: Hi! Is there a way to see whole custom attribute text? I have the same problem as above, text strings are cut off

Comment: @Wojtek Not at the moment, but if you hover over the event in the graph, you would see the full string.

Comment: @MikeBonnell addition of that feature is much appreciated.

Comment: We too would love to see this feature added. Would certainly help us with debugging and customer support.

Comment: likewise - would really love this feature.

Comment: What is the point of the custom events if you don't have access to the data?

Comment: Answers has always been a real-time, opinionated view of analytics. Our approach won't work for every app. You have access to the top 10 data elements per custom attribute that you send up to highlight the top attributes per event.

Comment: I'd like to express my interest in this feature as well. Collecting that opinionated view is excellent, but I actually want to see the text feedback that comes with it (and export it!). It's not enough that you show only the first few characters of the top 10 data elements.

Comment: Given that Fabric is being retired, if you want this functionality, I'd recommend setting up Google Analytics in Firebase and using Big Query to export the data.