# How to log on Fabrics a long message

Tags: android, google-fabric

I'm trying to write a long text log message on Fabrics system (Android), like this:

```
Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("Request:" + requestUrl + "\nResponse:" + json));
```

The message become cut, and can't find a way to expand it:

[image]

Even when the message is added as a custom attribute, like @Alexizamerican suggested,

```
Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("Requests"))
       .putCustomAttribute("Request", requestUrl + "\nResponse:" + json)
```

it stays cut in the Events Dashboard, see picture below:[image]

How to see the whole message?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

It's best to include longer messages as custom attributes of an event, rather than in the event name. For example:

```
Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("Requests"))
       .putCustomAttribute("Request", requestUrl + "\nResponse:" + json)
```

Check out 
https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/answers-events.html#custom-attributes
 for more details.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion, but the attributes are still cut, please see updated question

Comment: We cut-off the string in the UI but if you hover over the value a tooltip will appear with the full text.

Comment: @Alexizamerican can you please respond? As David said, it still cut-off the string. where can I see full length string? is there any limitation for length?

Comment: @Aks4125 Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: @Alexizamerican Is there no way to see the entire string? when hovering over only part of the string is shown. I also tried to inspect the element, in Chrome, still only part of the string is shown.